After submitting form on page I get an HTTP 500 error
so in this code I want to update login data, which works fine when submitting the form. But still when submitting, the page gets blocked by an HTTP 500 error. The code should be executed but the user must stay on the site. So there is no redirecting. I use XAMPP.
I hope you guys can help me!
<?php
session_start();
include "../PHP/db.php";

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    echo "User not logged in.";
    exit();
}

$loggedInUserId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$userId = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : $loggedInUserId;

if ($loggedInUserId == $userId && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['ueber'])) {
        $ueberText = !empty($_POST['ueber']) ? $_POST['ueber'] : "Hey there I am using Nifty Thrift!";
        $query = "UPDATE Benutzer SET Ueber = ? WHERE User_ID = ?";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute([$ueberText, $loggedInUserId]);
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        exit();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['confirm_password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $confirmPassword = $_POST['confirm_password'];

        if ($password === $confirmPassword) {
            $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $query = "UPDATE Benutzer SET Username = ?, Passwort = ? WHERE User_ID = ?";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute([$username, $hashedPassword, $loggedInUserId]);
            header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "Die Passwörter müssen übereinstimmen.";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_FILES['profile_picture'])) {
        $profilePicture = $_FILES['profile_picture'];
        $targetDir = "../Bilder/Profilbilder/$username/";
        $targetFile = $targetDir . basename($profilePicture['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($profilePicture['tmp_name'], $targetFile);

        $query = "UPDATE Benutzer SET Profilbild_Pfad = ? WHERE User_ID = ?";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute([$targetFile, $loggedInUserId]);
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        exit();
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['delete_ad'])) {
    $adId = $_POST['delete_ad'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM Inserat WHERE Inserat_ID = ? AND User_ID = ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([$adId, $loggedInUserId]);
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit();
}

try {
    // Fetch user details
    $query = "
        SELECT b.Username, b.Ort, b.Ueber, b.Profilbild_ID, p.Profilbild_Pfad
        FROM Benutzer b
        LEFT JOIN Profilbild p ON b.Profilbild_ID = p.Profilbild_ID
        WHERE b.User_ID = ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([$userId]);
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (!$user) {
        echo "User not found.";
        exit();
    }

    // Fetch user ads
    $queryAds = "
        SELECT i.Titel, i.Zustand, i.Preis, b.Bilder_Pfad, i.Inserat_ID, i.Erstellungsdatum
        FROM Inserat i
        LEFT JOIN Bild b ON i.Inserat_ID = b.Inserat_ID
        WHERE i.User_ID = ?";
    $stmtAds = $pdo->prepare($queryAds);
    $stmtAds->execute([$userId]);
    $userAds = $stmtAds->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Profile View</title>
    <!-- Include the Google Font League Spartan -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=League+Spartan:wght@400;700&display=swap">
    <!-- Material Symbols -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/body.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/navbar.css">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav"><?php include "navbar.php" ?></div>
<h1><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_id']); ?></h1>
<div class="container">
    <?php if ($loggedInUserId == $userId): ?>
        <button class="edit-btn" onclick="toggleEdit()">✏️</button>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="profile-container">
        <div class="profile-header">
            <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user['Profilbild_Pfad']); ?>" alt="Profile Picture" id="profile-picture" onclick="triggerUpload()">
            <div class="profile-info">
                <h1><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user['Username']); ?></h1>
                <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user['Ort']); ?></p>
                <?php if ($loggedInUserId == $userId): ?>
                    <p>Zuletzt online: vor xx Tagen</p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php if ($loggedInUserId != $userId): ?>
                <button class="message-btn" onclick="location.href='chat.html'">Nachricht senden</button>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-details">
            <h2>Über mich:</h2>
            <?php if ($loggedInUserId == $userId): ?>
                <p id="ueber-text"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user['Ueber']); ?></p>
                <form id="edit-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none;">
                    <textarea name="ueber" rows="4"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user['Ueber']); ?></textarea>
                    <h2>Benutzerdaten:</h2>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Neuer Benutzername" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user['Username']); ?>">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Neues Passwort">
                    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Passwort bestätigen">
                    <button type="submit">Speichern</button>
                    <input type="file" name="profile_picture" id="profile-picture-upload" class="upload-form">
                </form>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user['Ueber']); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <button class="active" onclick="showTab('kleiderschrank')">Kleiderschrank</button>
            <button onclick="showTab('bewertungen')">Bewertungen</button>
        </div>
        <div id="kleiderschrank" class="content">
            <?php if (!empty($userAds)): ?>
                <?php foreach ($userAds as $ad): ?>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ad['Bilder_Pfad']); ?>" alt="Produkt Bild">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3><a href="inserat_anzeigen.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ad['Inserat_ID']); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($ad['Titel']); ?></a></h3>
                            <p>Zustand: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($ad['Zustand']); ?></p>
                            <p class="price">Preis: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($ad['Preis']); ?>€</p>
                            <p class="date">Erstellt am: <?php echo htmlspecialchars(date("d.m.Y", strtotime($ad['Erstellungsdatum']))); ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <?php if ($loggedInUserId == $userId): ?>
                            <div class="actions">
                                <form method="post" style="display:inline;">
                                    <button class="delete-btn" type="submit" name="delete_ad" value="<?php echo $ad['Inserat_ID']; ?>">️</button>
                                </form>
                                <button class="edit-btn" onclick="editAd(<?php echo $ad['Inserat_ID']); ?>)">✏️</button>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p>Noch hast du nichts eingestellt...</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function toggleEdit() {
        var form = document.getElementById('edit-form');
        var ueberText = document.getElementById('ueber-text');
        var container = document.querySelector('.container');

        if (form.style.display === 'none') {
            form.style.display = 'block';
            ueberText.style.display = 'none';
            container.classList.add('editing');
        } else {
            form.style.display = 'none';
            ueberText.style.display = 'block';
            container.classList.remove('editing');
        }
    }

    function showTab(tabId) {
        document.getElementById('kleiderschrank').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('bewertungen').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('.tabs .active').classList.remove('active');
        document.querySelector(`.tabs button[onclick="showTab('${tabId}')"]`).classList.add('active');
        document.getElementById(tabId).style.display = 'block';
    }

    function editAd(adId) {
        // Implement ad editing logic here
        alert("Edit ad " + adId);
    }

    function triggerUpload() {
        var form = document.getElementById('edit-form');
        if (form.style.display === 'block') {
            document.getElementById('profile-picture-upload').click();
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
<footer>
    <p>&copy; 2024 NiftyThrift. All rights reserved.</p>
    <div class="social-media-icons">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/instagramlogo.png" alt="Instagram Logo"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../Bilder/pinterestlogo.png" alt="Pinterest Logo"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/tiktoklogo.png" alt="TikTok Logo"></a>
    </div>
</footer>


I tried rerouting the form to an empty handler with just session_start() and rerouting back to the page but it didn't work.

Check the web server error log for potential clues.

put error_reporting(-1)  at top of script and then check for error

Please add the error threshold here.
